# cannot run zipkin-dependencies - module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module

Tags: zipkin

Im running zipkin version 2.24.1 with Elasticsearch version 7.17.10 on different servers which work fine.
when I try to run zipkin-dependencies in order the see dependencies in my UI Im getting this error:

```
23/05/10 18:26:34 DEBUG ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Spark conf properties: spark.ui.enabled=false
23/05/10 18:26:34 DEBUG ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Spark conf properties: es.index.read.missing.as.empty=true
23/05/10 18:26:34 DEBUG ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Spark conf properties: es.nodes.wan.only=false
23/05/10 18:26:34 DEBUG ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Spark conf properties: es.net.ssl.keystore.location=
23/05/10 18:26:34 DEBUG ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Spark conf properties: es.net.ssl.keystore.pass=
23/05/10 18:26:34 DEBUG ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Spark conf properties: es.net.ssl.truststore.location=
23/05/10 18:26:34 DEBUG ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Spark conf properties: es.net.ssl.truststore.pass=
23/05/10 18:26:34 INFO ElasticsearchDependenciesJob: Processing spans from zipkin:span-2023-05-10/span
23/05/10 18:26:34 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.findPartitions(RestService.java:216)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDD.esPartitions$lzycompute(AbstractEsRDD.scala:79)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDD.esPartitions(AbstractEsRDD.scala:78)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.AbstractEsRDD.getPartitions(AbstractEsRDD.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:269)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:269)
        at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$4.apply(Partitioner.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$4.apply(Partitioner.scala:78)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:296)
        at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$1.apply(RDD.scala:714)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$groupBy$1.apply(RDD.scala:714)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.groupBy(RDD.scala:713)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.groupBy(JavaRDDLike.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.groupBy(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at zipkin2.dependencies.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDependenciesJob.run(ElasticsearchDependenciesJob.java:189)
        at zipkin2.dependencies.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDependenciesJob.run(ElasticsearchDependenciesJob.java:170)
        at zipkin2.dependencies.ZipkinDependenciesJob.main(ZipkinDependenciesJob.java:79)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field protected byte[] java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.buf accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @1c0dc10
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.util.IOUtils.<clinit>(IOUtils.java:53)
        ... 28 more
```

I tried finding any indication from the log and on the zipkin documentation but couldn't find